# Trying to scrape from multiple links

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The goal of this script is to visit a website, generate links to the specific products, and then scrape from those generated links.

In this script, the script will gain links from the four featured products seen on the product homepage through the attribute defined. The links are saved in a variable 'links', which contain four urls to the four featured products.

Then, I will use requests to request each of those urls of the products to scrape the data using BeautifulSoup.

Here is my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.vatainc.com/"
service = service.Service('/Users/Name/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
service.start()
capabilities = {'chrome.binary': '/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, capabilities)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'product-name')]/a")]


html = requests.get(links).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
products = soup.findAll("div")
print(products)
```

The error code I get:

> No connection adapters were found for
>   '['https://www.vatainc.com/0240-bonnie-bone-marrow-biopsy-skills-trainertm.html',
>   'https://www.vatainc.com/0910-seymour-iitm-wound-care-model-1580.html',
>   'https://www.vatainc.com/2410-chester-chesttm-with-new-advanced-arm-1197.html',
>   'https://www.vatainc.com/2365-advanced-four-vein-venipuncture-training-aidtm-dermalike-iitm-latex-free.html']'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`links` is the list of strings (URLs). You cannot pass list as `url` argument to `requests.get()`. Try to iterate through this list and pass each URL one by one and get each page:

```
for link in links:
    html = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    products = soup.findAll("div")
    print(products)
```